# How to store spring session in redis

Tags: java, spring, redis

I am New to redis. I want store spring  session in Redis.

I create spring application with xml configuration. i added redis and jedis id's

```
<bean id="jedisConnectionFactoryclass="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
             IP address
    <property name="hostName" value="http://127.0.0.1"/>
             Password
    <property name="password" value=""/>
             Port number
    <property name="port" value="6379"/>
             Timeout time Default 2000
    <property name="timeout" value="100000"/>
             Connection pool configuration reference

             usePool: Whether to use connection pool
    <property name="usePool" value="true"/>
 </bean>

<bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jedisConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="keySerializer">
        <bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer"/>
    </property>
    <property name="valueSerializer">
        <bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer"/>
    </property>
    <property name="hashKeySerializer">
        <bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer"/>
    </property>
    <property name="hashValueSerializer">
        <bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer"/>
    </property>
             Open transaction
    <property name="enableTransactionSupport" value="true"></property>
</bean>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
        <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

above dependencies are added in pom.
Nothing is showing in redis-cli monitor.
i Installed redis -cli one server 196.123.0.14

Comment: Are you able to start the application without any issues? you said you installed redis on 196.123.0.14 but in configuration xml I see redis hostname as 127.0.0.1. Please check configuration again.

Comment: application is running . How to give host-name. i saw in stackoverflow like redis://196.123.0.14 is it correct?